# Decode base64 returns foreign characters

Tags: vb.net

Two methods, one to encode base64 and the other to UndEncode base64 - using the sample string "password" the encoded result is: `OY5QsDipwgvvhHZk32fzG7vd7m4jvhPr9gyP6smEARE=`

When using the above result to UnEncode, the following is the result: `猀猀眀漀爀搀�`

`passwordFormat = 2`

Why is this returning Chinese characters instead of US?

```
    Public Function EncodePassword(ByVal pass As String, ByVal passwordFormat As Integer, ByVal salt As String) As String
        If passwordFormat = 0 Then Return pass
        Dim bIn As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass)
        Dim bSalt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(salt)
        Dim bAll As Byte() = New Byte(bSalt.Length + bIn.Length - 1) {}
        Dim bRet As Byte() = Nothing
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length)
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length)

        If passwordFormat = 1 Then
            Dim s As HashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create(_HashAlgorithmType)

            If s Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ProviderException("Could not create a hash algorithm")
            End If

            bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll)
        Else
            bRet = EncryptPassword(bAll)
        End If

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet)
    End Function

    Public Function UnEncodePassword(ByVal pass As String, ByVal passwordFormat As Integer) As String
        Select Case passwordFormat
            Case 0
                Return pass
            Case 1
                Throw New ProviderException("Provider can not decode hashed password")
            Case Else
                Dim bIn As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(pass)
                Dim bRet As Byte() = DecryptPassword(bIn)
                If bRet Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
                'Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bRet)
                Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bRet, SALT_SIZE_IN_BYTES, bRet.Length - SALT_SIZE_IN_BYTES)
        End Select
  End Function
```

Comment: corrected language - Encode not Encrypt, and UnEncode not Decrypt

Comment: I referring to the two functions listed to Encode and UnEncode

Comment: Seems like the password was "ssword".  The bytes in the 16-bit Unicode codepoints are swapped, somehow.  Guessing at an endianness problem is probably unwise.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you?

Comment: not using the hashed format... using `bRet = EncryptPassword(bAll)`

Comment: How does the UnEncodePassword() function know the correct size of the salt?  SALT_SIZE_IN_BYTES seems but a guess, EncodePassword() does not enforce that size.  You'll get Chinese if it is off by 1.

Comment: I'm using code from an old AccessMembershipProvider to update an old site to use a low level form of password encryption/encoding. Any help on how to make this work? I had the `SALT_SIZE_IN_BYTES` set to 6 and a fixed salt var.